# Swift Viewcontroller.type does not have a member named simpleClass

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift, wrote a class as below and I get an error as

> `Viewcontroller.type` does not have a member named `simpleClass`

```
class CheckClass {
    var simpleInt = 0
    func checkClassMethod() -> String {
        var simpleString = "The value of Integer is \(simpleInt)"
        return simpleString
    }
}
var simpleClass = CheckClass()
simpleClass.simpleInt = 5

var simpleString = simpleClass.checkClassMethod()
println(simpleString)
```

Comment: I think moving the latter part of the code into some method such as `viewDidLoad` would work.

Comment: Yes it worked, I have a doubt, whether we can have more than one class in a file? and class inside class (nested classes) ?

Comment: I don't know, you can test it and see if there is errors.